# In Android media player, how do I get "bytes loaded"?

Tags: android, media-player

I am working on **android media players**. I want to know how to get the **number of bytes that have been loaded** since the video streaming starts.

Is there any API or way to compute that?

Answer (score 1):

There's no current way to do this. All you can do is register an OnBufferingUpdateListener to receive the percentage of the bytes buffered, as its buffer progress increases.